# jq - assign to the key name the value from a variable

Tags: json, jq

I have a `JSON` object  `{"b":1,"c":2}` and want to put this object under the object with the key named `xyz`.

However, the key name is coming from the shell variable. So in other words, I first need to get the key name, and after that put `{"b":1,"c":2}` under it so the result looks like following:

```
{
  "xyz": {
    "b": 1,
    "c": 2
  }
}
```

I came up with the following statement. It does the job, but want to know if there are more efficient ways to do it by eliminating temporary `new` entry.

```
jq -n --arg a "xyz"  '{"b":1,"c":2} as $new | {$new} | with_entries(if .key == "new" then .key = $a else . end)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it very simply as below

```
jq -n --arg a "xyz" '{ ($a): { "b": 1 ,"c": 2 } }'
```

or with contents from stdin

```
echo '{ "b": 1 ,"c": 2 }' | jq -n --arg a "xyz" '{ ($a): inputs }'
```

or without `-n`

```
echo '{ "b": 1 ,"c": 2 }' | jq --arg a "xyz" '{ ($a): . }'
```

or with both keyname and the object configurable

```
jq -n --arg k "xyz" --argjson v '{ "b": 1 ,"c": 2 }' '{ ($k): $v }'
```